# How to get the source code of the ajaxcontroltoolkit 2012 release?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I want the source code for the ajaxcontroltoolkit 2012. I tried a lot but I get only binaries there does not appear to be any source code. can anyone help me how to get the source code for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the source code or various release from its [codeplex page](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/)

In [source code tab](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) there is link in right side to download the source.

[image: Downloaded source screen shot]

Comment: Thanks for reply. However, still no hope. Only binaries are available there too.

Comment: actually I only need source code for the AjaxFileUpload control only. can I get it?

Comment: Well you got complete source code as I have attached screen shot in my answer. What else ? Do you want ONLY AJAXFILEUPLOAD CONTROL as a separate project or dll from the whole control suite ?

Comment: Sorry I am late. This is old release. not the new one. I think there is no source code available for 2012 release. Thanks

Comment: In svn it is written that "June 2012 Release." http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/1014bf767f65. Did you mean Visual Studio 2012 release .sln file ?

Comment: In svn it is written that "June 2012 Release." what next ?